# I am getting " Line 9: error: cannot find symbol" error for the below code: Squares of sorted array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {

    public int[] sortedSquares(int[] A) {
        int[] b =new int[A.length];
        int k = 0;
        for(int i:A){
            k=i*i;
            b.add(k);  
        }
        Arrays.sort(b);
        return b;    
    }
}
```

Comment: `b.add(k);`: an array, like `int[]`, doesn't have an `add` method

Comment: It seems that there is no need to sort array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to add things into array, there is no `add` method for array, use index for adding values to arrays

```
for(int i =0; i<A.length; i++){
    k=A[i]*A[i];   // you can also use Math.pow()
    b[i]=k; 
}
```

Making above clode clear and clean. by using for loop

```
for(int i =0; i<A.length; i++){
    b[i]=A[i]*A[i];   // you can also use Math.pow() 
}
```

And also by using for each

```
    int k = 0;
    for(int i:A){
        b[k]=i*i;
        k++;  
    }
```

Comment: OR `b[i] = A[i]*A[i];`.

Comment: yup that reduces one line @Pshemo thank you

Comment: It also reduces *need* for `k` variable so we can remove `int k = 0;` (so we saved two lines :)

Comment: yup perfect @Pshemo